# How to import 20 thousand product from large XML file in a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, nokogiri, sax

Here is my Products controller:

```
  def import
    if params[:xml_file]
      file = params[:xml_file]
      doc = Nokogiri::XML::Document.parse(file)
      total_product = doc.xpath('//offer').take(params[:limit_number].to_i).length

      Product.import(doc, params[:category_id], params[:stranger_category], params[:limit_number])
      redirect_to products_path, notice: "#{total_product} Product added."
    end
  end
```

Here is my product models code:

```
def self.import(doc, category, cat_id, lit_num)
  parsed_products = doc.xpath('//offer').take(lit_num.to_i)

  parsed_products.each do |product|
    next unless product.at_xpath('categoryId').text == cat_id
    Product.create!(
      price: product.at_xpath('price').text,
      category_id: product.at_xpath('categoryId').text.gsub(cat_id, category),
      remote_image_url: product.at_xpath('picture').text.strip,
      brand_id: product.at_xpath('vendor').text,
      title: product.at_xpath('name').text,
      description: product.at_xpath('description').text
    )
  end
end
```

This is my upload form:

```
h2.text-center Import Products

= form_tag import_products_path, multipart: true do |f|
  = file_field_tag :xml_file
  br
  = label_tag 'Mine Category'
  = select_tag :category_id, options_for_select(Category.all.map {|c| [c.name, c.id ] })
  br
  = label_tag 'Stranger Category: '

  = text_field_tag 'stranger_category'
  br

  = label_tag 'Limit: '

  = text_field_tag "limit_number"

  br
  br
  = submit_tag "Import"
```

This code  works for small files but not my XML.

I was reading "[[HOW TO] Parse large XML files in Ruby](http://rohitmenon.com/index.php/how-to-parse-large-xml-files-in-ruby/#comment-267617)"  and like this code but can't get the same result as my code.

This is my import looks like:
http://prntscr.com/ar0hn8

Here is my XML file:
http://gist.github.com/saroar/0851b55e3c7add4c3deff0b7e306d004

Comment: Rather than use Rails to import it, have you looked into using the tools that come with your DBM? It'd be a lot faster.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[mcve]". Don't use links to your XML. Instead, summarize it by reducing it to the bare minimum necessary to demonstrate the problem. Links rot then break, and will then leave your question making no sense to others in the future. We don't know what the problem is; Does your code crash? Does it fail to import everything? Without that information we're left wondering how to help and any answers would be wild guesses.

Comment: Thanks for answer my code is working find and but when xml file is large I am out of memory in my macbook I have 8gb rem but  it crash my server :( and what is DBM?

Answer (score 0):

`Nokogiri::XML` attempts to load the entire file into memory, which won't work with large input files.

If you want to continue loading this file in Rails, one alternative would be to use a SAX parser (http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/master/Nokogiri/XML/SAX) which parses the XML file line-by-line rather than all at once.

Or, you could look into tools that your database provides, as @the-tin-man was suggesting. MySQL has a tool to load XML directly: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-xml.html